# Concatenate two string program not giving correct output

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
char * sstrcat(char*,char*);
void main() {
    char *c;
    char s[100] = "abcde";
    char t[] = "fghi";
    c = sstrcat(s,t);
    printf("%s",c);
}

char* sstrcat(char *s,char *t) {
    char* temp = s;
    while(*s++ != '\0');
    while((*s++ = *t++) != '\0');

    return temp;
}
```

Above written code I am getting output **abcde** but expected output is concatenation of string `s` and `t`.

Please help me to figure out what mistake I am doing ?
thanks.

Comment: When you concatenate you should start at the '\0' character of `s` to overwrite it, otherwise if you leave it there then it will signal the end of the string even tho you successfully concatenated the other string after the '\0' char.

Comment: The problem is in `while(*s++ != '\0')`, when you found null terminator, you're still incrementing it, leaving it there ...

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
while(*s++ != '\0');
```

will increment `s` after the comparison has been made, leaving `'\0'`, which is a string terminator in your array.

If you can use a debugger you will find that all values are in your array, its just that `printf` will stop at `'\0'`

Answer (score 1):

Just move your string iterator back one char due to '\0' (after you execute `while(*s++ != '\0');`) and that fixes your code.

---

Explanation:

Your `s` string is `"abcde\0"`. After the first while loop, the iterator will be at `'\0'`. If you leave it there you will concatenate both strings obtaining the result `"abcde\0fghi\0"` which prints `"abcde"` due to the first `'\0'`.

Instead, if you move back the `s` string iterator one position with (`s--`) you will have this string as result `"abcdefghi\0"` which prints the string as you expect.

Fixed Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char * sstrcat(char*,char*);

void main() {
    char *c;
    char s[100] = "abcde";
    char t[] = "fghi";
    c = sstrcat(s,t);
    printf("%s\n",c);
}

char* sstrcat(char *s,char *t) {
    char* temp = s;
    while(*s++ != '\0');
    s--;
    while((*s++ = *t++) != '\0');

    return temp;
}
```